# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 dock panel preview order stable?

Tags: panel, dock, ubuntu-dock

Let's say I have 2 Terminals open in the background.

I click on the Terminal icon on the dock, it shows me the preview of two windows and I click on the first one. I discover that this is not the right one.

Now I click on the icon again, get the preview of two windows again and select the second one. I get same terminal again! Ubuntu has switched the order of the previews in the meanwhile.

Is there a setting that keeps the order of these window previews stable?